# How to optimize this codes of graphs with tikz

Tags: tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying to learn Tikz and I want to know if there is a way to optimize this 2 graphs. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}       
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.6cm, x=.6cm,font=\small]

\draw [dashed,-latex](-1,1)  --  (1,1);
\draw [-latex](1,1)  --  (3,1);
\draw [-latex](3,1)  --  (5,1);
\draw [-latex](5,1)  --  (7,1);
\draw [-latex](7,1)  --  (9,1);
\draw [dashed,-latex](9,1)  --  (11,1);

\draw [dashed,-latex](-1,3)  --  (1,3);
\draw [-latex](1,3)  --  (3,3);
\draw [-latex](3,3)  --  (5,3);
\draw [-latex](5,3)  --  (7,3);
\draw [-latex](7,3)  --  (9,3);
\draw [dashed,-latex](9,3)  --  (11,3);

\draw [dashed,-latex](-1,5)  --  (1,5);
\draw [-latex](1,5)  --  (3,5);
\draw [-latex](3,5)  --  (5,5);
\draw [-latex](5,5)  --  (7,5);
\draw [-latex](7,5)  --  (9,5);
\draw [dashed,-latex](9,5)  --  (11,5);

\draw [dashed,-latex](-1,7)  --  (1,7);
\draw [-latex](1,7)  --  (3,7);
\draw [-latex](3,7)  --  (5,7);
\draw [-latex](5,7)  --  (7,7);
\draw [-latex](7,7)  --  (9,7);
\draw [dashed,-latex](9,7)  --  (11,7);

\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](1,-1)  --  (1,1);
\draw [-latex,blue](1,1)  --  (1,3);
\draw [-latex,blue](1,3)  --  (1,5);
\draw [-latex,blue](1,5)  --  (1,7);
\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](1,7)  --  (1,9);

\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](3,-1)  --  (3,1);
\draw [-latex,blue](3,1)  --  (3,3);
\draw [-latex,blue](3,3)  --  (3,5);
\draw [-latex,blue](3,5)  --  (3,7);
\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](3,7)  --  (3,9);

\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](5,-1)  --  (5,1);
\draw [-latex,blue](5,1)  --  (5,3);
\draw [-latex,blue](5,3)  --  (5,5);
\draw [-latex,blue](5,5)  --  (5,7);
\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](5,7)  --  (5,9);

\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](7,-1)  --  (7,1);
\draw [-latex,blue](7,1)  --  (7,3);
\draw [-latex,blue](7,3)  --  (7,5);
\draw [-latex,blue](7,5)  --  (7,7);
\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](7,7)  --  (7,9);

\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](9,-1)  --  (9,1);
\draw [-latex,blue](9,1)  --  (9,3);
\draw [-latex,blue](9,3)  --  (9,5);
\draw [-latex,blue](9,5)  --  (9,7);
\draw [dashed,-latex,blue](9,7)  --  (9,9);

\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (1,1) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (1,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (1,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (1,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,1) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (5,1) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,1) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,1) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (5,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (5,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (5,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

%AND THIS OTHER


\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.6cm, x=.6cm,font=\small]

\draw [latex-](3,1)  --  (1,3);
\draw [latex-](1,3)  --  (3,3);
\draw [latex-](3,3)  --  (3,1);

\draw [-latex](7,1)  --  (7,3);
\draw [-latex](7,3)  --  (9,3);
\draw [-latex](9,3)  --  (7,1);

\draw [-latex](7,7)  --  (9,7);
\draw [-latex](9,7)  --  (7,9);
\draw [-latex](7,9)  --  (7,7);

\draw [-latex](1,7)  --  (3,9);
\draw [-latex](3,9)  --  (3,7);
\draw [-latex](3,7)  --  (1,7);

\draw [latex-latex,dashed,red](3,7)  --  (7,3);
\draw [latex-latex,dashed,red](1,3)  --  (1,7);
\draw [latex-latex,dashed,red](3,1)  --  (7,1);
\draw [latex-latex,dashed,red](9,3)  --  (9,7);
\draw [latex-latex,dashed,red](7,9)  --  (3,9);
\draw [latex-latex,dashed,red](7,7)  --  (3,3);

\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,1) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north]{(243)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{(143)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{(132)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (3,9) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{(123)} ;

\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,1) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north]{(142)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{(234)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{(124)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (7,9) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{(134)} ;

\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (1,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{(12)(34)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (1,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east]{e} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{(13)(24)} ;
\filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] (9,7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{(14)(23)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

I know it is large but I am trying to know how to write in this language. Also if you know a concise page or book to learn how to use Tikz, it would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: It is rather easy to simplify it but the most immediate simplification arises from introducing `\foreach` loops. They are described in the pgfmanual in section **87 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can one avoid repetition? There are many ways, but here I focus on

- `\foreach` loops,
- styles,
- `pic`s

The first figure can be drawn with two nested `\foreach` loops, in which the repeating directives are stored in styles. The second figure uses a pic with named subnodes that get rotated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}       

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.6cm, x=.6cm,font=\small,bullet/.style={inner sep=0pt,
 minimum size=4pt,circle,fill=black!40,draw=black!80}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmax}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ymax}{4}
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX] in {1,...,\Xmax}
 {\foreach \Y [remember=\Y as \LastY] in {1,...,\Ymax}
  {
   \node[bullet] (X\X\Y) at (2*\X,2*\Y){};
   \ifnum\Y>1
    \draw [-latex,blue]  (X\X\LastY) -- (X\X\Y);
   \else
    \draw [dashed,latex-,blue]  (X\X\Y) -- ++(0,-2);
   \fi
   \ifnum\X>1
    \draw [-latex]  (X\LastX\Y) -- (X\X\Y);
   \else
    \draw [dashed,latex-]  (X\X\Y) -- ++(-2,0);
   \fi
   \ifnum\Y=\Ymax
    \draw [dashed,-latex,blue]  (X\X\Y) -- ++(0,2);
   \fi
   \ifnum\X=\Xmax
    \draw [dashed,-latex]  (X\X\Y) -- ++(2,0);
   \fi
  }
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

%AND THIS OTHER


\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.6cm, x=.6cm,font=\small,bullet/.style={inner sep=0pt,
 minimum size=4pt,circle,fill=black!40,draw=black!80}]
 \tikzset{pics/.cd,
 tricle/.style={code={
 \draw (0,0) node[bullet] (-A){} (2,0) node[bullet] (-B){} (0,2) node[bullet]
 (-C){};
 \draw[latex-] (-A) -- (-B);
 \draw[latex-] (-B) -- (-C);
 \draw[latex-] (-C) -- (-A);
 }}}
  \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {\path (-45+\X*90:2cm) pic[rotate=-90+\X*90] (T-\X) {tricle};}
  \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially 4)] in {1,...,4}
  { \draw[dashed,red,latex-latex] (T-\X-B) -- (T-\LastX-C);}
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {{(134)},{e},{(243)},{(13)(24)}}
  { \node[anchor=\Y*90+135] at (T-\Y-C.{\Y*90-45}) {\X};}
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {{(14)(23)},{(123)},{(12)(34)},{(142)}}
  { \node[anchor=\Y*90+135] at (T-\Y-B.{\Y*90-45}) {\X};}
  \draw[dashed,red,latex-latex,text=black] (T-1-A) node[left] {(124)}
  -- (T-3-A) node[right]{(143)};
  \draw[dashed,red,latex-latex,text=black] (T-2-A) node[right] {(132)}
  -- (T-4-A) node[left]{(234)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I have a question, if I want to change the size of the arrowhead, how I do it on that code? Because normaly I put [length=3mm] at the end of -latex, but here I don't know.

Comment: @J.Rodriguez All you need to do is to load `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` and then you can use the arrowhead `Latex[length=3mm]`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And one last question, what is the first X in (X\X\Y) in the first code?

Comment: @J.Rodriguez That's just a random label that I chose. You could replace the first `X`, i.e. the one without backslash, by `cute furry rodent`, and if you replace it everywhere, it will still work. (I just do not like using plain numbers because there *might* be confusion with the anchors.)

Answer (score 1):

#### First figure:

I created nodes and not points as in your code because it allows you to draw arrows that go from edge to edge without crossing the nodes.

#### Second figure:

Not having understood the logic of the textual numbering of the nodes in the second figure, it is possible to simplify the code of the creation of the nodes, but not that of their text.  *Unless you explain this numbering logic.*

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}    

\begin{document}

\tikzset{noeud/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,outer sep=0pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.6cm, x=.6cm,font=\small,tips= on proper draw]

% Creation of nodes
\foreach \x in {-1,1,...,9,11}{
    \foreach \y in {-1,1,...,9,11}{
        \node[noeud] at (\x,\y)(\x-\y){};
        }
    }
% Inside arrows between the nodes.  
\foreach \x [remember =\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {1,3,...,9}{
    \foreach \y [remember =\y as \lasty (initially 1)] in {1,3,...,9}{
            \node[noeud,draw,fill=black!40,draw=black!80] at (\x,\y){};
            \draw[-latex] (\lastx-\y)--(\x-\y);
            \draw[-latex,blue](\x-\lasty)--(\x-\y);
            }
    }       

% Horizontal external arrows.
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \lastx using int(\x-2)] in {1,11}{
    \foreach \y in {1,3,...,9}{
    \draw[dashed,-latex](\lastx-\y)--(\x-\y);
    }
}

% Vertical external arrows. 
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \lasty using int(\y-2)] in {1,11}{
    \foreach \x in {1,3,...,9}{
    \draw[dashed,-latex,blue](\x-\lasty)--(\x-\y);
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Jmm is not that easy to understand the labeling of the second graph, that one is the Cayley's Graph of the alternating group ($A_4$) based on the generators {(123),(12)(34)}. So it is not so easy to explain. But thanks.

Comment: On this site, it is asking to vote for the answers instead of saying thank you in the comments. Read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes, as I did on the answer of marmot.